# Maximal Magnitude of Fourier Transform

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

Assume you are given a length-$n$ vector $x\in\mathbb{C}$ with elements $x_0$ through $x_{n-1}$. Define the Fourier transform of $x$ as

$$ X(e^{j\theta}) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x_k e^{-jk\theta}. $$

I'm interested in the maximum of its magnitude, i.e., on

$$ \max_{\theta} |X(e^{j\theta})|^2. $$

Are there any non-trivial results for general $x$?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you find this trivial, but this is about the only thing you can say:

$$\left|X(e^{j\theta})\right|=\left|\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x_ke^{-jk\theta}\right|\le\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|x_k|$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I was afraid that this is really the only thing one can show, as this bound is rather loose in many cases...